# session in webpy - getting username in all classes

Tags: python, session, post, web.py

I am using webpy framework for my project. I am logging in from my 'login' class of main.py program. I want to get the username in some other class.  I tried with session and experimented with it for a long time. I have implemented session like below.

```
store = web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
session = web.session.Session(app,store,initializer={'login': 0,'privilege': 0})
```

in my login class of main.py the following code will work when user submit username and password.(This is the post method 0f my login class).

```
class login:
    def POST(self):
            i = web.input(form_submit="Login")
            authdb = sqlite3.connect('database/users.db')
            conn = authdb.cursor()
            if i.form_submit=='Login':
                check = conn.execute('select * from user_details where username=?and password=?', (i.username, i.password))
                n=check.fetchall()
                if len(n)!=0:
                        session.loggedin = True
                        session.username = i.username
            return render.home('Home')
                else: return render.display('Wrong username or password !')
```

I want to get the username in some other class. I tried to access the username with `session.username` , but it shows the following error.    `AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'username'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide the default values for `loggedin` and `username` in session's `initializer` `dict`. The error seems to appear when those attributes are not set (i.e. when user isn't logged in) and you try to access them.

Comment: Thanks Andrey for your suggestion.. Finally I got the solution after 3 days..!

Comment: @Unni, you're welcome! I faced the exact same problem when started using webpy.

Answer (score 3):

I have made the following changes in my main.py program.

Changes made : Instead of just giving

```
session = web.session.Session(app,store,initializer={'login': 0,'privilege': 0,'user':'anonymous','loggedin':False})
```

I added following lines of code,

```
if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    session = web.session.Session(app,store,initializer={'login': 0,'privilege': 0,'user':'anonymous','loggedin':False})
    web.config._session = session
else:
    session = web.config._session
```

I also made a small change in initilizer dictionary, inititialized user as anonymous and loggedin as false.
Thanks to Andrey for giving me the thread.