# concept of session and cookie in web development python

Tags: python, session, authentication, cookies, web.py

I am very new to web development, i am working on `web.py` framework to develop a small web application. suppose the login screen is `localhost:9090/login`, after the succesfull login it is redirecting to next page `localhost:9090/details` and after clicking another button `add` its again redirecting to `localhost:9090/details/details_entry`.

But when i tried directly `localhost:9090/details`on browser its working and able to see the page without even logged in . So after googling a lot came to know that i need to use `session concept` , but i am tired as of now for busy schedule on searching about web concepts in google. 
Can anyone let me know the concept of

1. `session` (Actually why it is created and how to use it after login through page in python)
2. Actually whats the complete concept of `user authentication` , 
   What are the steps to follow to create a user login page 
   And steps to follow after user logged in with details
   what happens when user logouts and how to session code in python

I expect what ever the language it is but the concept of developing login screen and redirecting to next url by creating some sessions ids is same, so the user authentication concept is very important and may be this question is useful to others.

**Edited Code**

**--------------**

**Login.py**

```
import os
import sys
import web
from web import form



render = web.template.render('templates/')


urls = (
  '/',   'Login',
  '/projects',  'Projects',
  '/project_details',  'Project_Details',  
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())


web.config.debug = False
db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='Python_Web', user='root', pw='redhat')
settings = {}
store = web.session.DBStore(db, 'sessions')
session = web.session.Session(app, store, initializer={'user': None})

class Login:

    login_form = form.Form( 
        form.Textbox('username', form.notnull),
        form.Password('password', form.notnull),
        form.Button('Login'),
        )

    def GET(self):
        form = self.login_form()
        return render.login(form)

def POST(self):
    if not self.login_form.validates():
        return render.login(self.login_form)
    i = web.input()
    username = i.username
    password = i.password
    user = db.select('user',
        where = 'user_login = $username', 
        vars = {'username': username}
    if username == user['username'] and password == user['password']:
        session.user = username
        raise web.seeother('/projects')

    else:
        return render.login_error(form)    

def auth_required(func):
    def proxyfunc(self, *args, **kw):
        print session.user,"=======> Session stored"
        try:
            if session.user:
              return func(self, *args, **kw)
        except:
            pass
        raise web.seeother("/")
    return proxyfunc

class Projects:

    project_list = form.Form( 
        form.Button('Add Project'),
        )

    @auth_required
    def GET(self):
        project_form = self.project_list()
        return render.projects(project_form)  

   def POST(self):
        raise web.seeother('/project_details')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.internalerror = web.debugerror
    app.run()
```

In the above code after successfull login the page is redirecting to next page. Here i need to implement session concept, but i was stuck on where to implement session code in the above code. Can anyone please point me to a right way on where to write session code in the above py code for login page. After this worked need to implement logout functionality in the same py file

Edited code after implementing `auth_required` function and got the below error

**Result:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 420, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 396, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "/home/local/user/python_webcode/index.py", line 102, in proxyfunc
    print session.user,"=======> Session Stored"
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/session.py", line 71, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._data, name)
AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: Have a look at google app engine. It includes a lot of services and you can make use of google authentication. I mean: Google will handle almost all the authentication your you. And it is free to play around with. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingusers

Comment: yes, or maybe look at a more comprehensive web framework, like Django?  It will take care of sessions + cookies for user authentication for you, and just give you a nice abstraction..

Comment: yeah i thought to use django first , but as i had small requirement for only three pages like login page,list page, formpage. so i selected web.py framework and i ws stuck near sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web.py provides [session](http://webpy.org/cookbook/sessions) abstraction and several session stores. What you have to do, is to write login controller, display the form on GET, and find user and perform password check on POST, then store the user in session and kill the session on logout. After it you may write decorator that checks if user exists in session to use it over controller methods. Anyway, user authentication concept is mostly the same in all web apps.

If you need already working solution for web.py then you may take a look at this module: http://jpscaletti.com/webpy_auth/

If you decided to implement login youself, the simplest auth decorator will probably look like this:

```
def auth_required(func):
    def proxyfunc(self, *args, **kw):
        try:
            if session.user:
              # user is logged in
              return func(self, *args, **kw)
        except:
            pass
        # user is not logged in
        raise web.seeother("/login")
    return proxyfunc
```

Then you will be able to use @auth_required before your GET and POST methods in controllers like this:

```
class Projects:
    @auth_required
    def GET(self):
        pass
```

Comment: so what happening here is i can able to save the user details sucessfully like "session.user = user", but when i tried to access this "session.user" in another function of another class it is showing AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'user'.If i got this session.user data in another class then game is over as i can write auth_required function and prevents the user from accessing page without login

Comment: Perhaps your issue could be related to using session session with reloader http://webpy.org/cookbook/session_with_reloader

Comment: hey thank you very very much Andrey, i have got the this link which have answered previously by you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382886/session-in-webpy-getting-username-in-all-classes , I have used the code given by unni if web.config.get('_session') is None:...... By using this now it worked. Once again hearty thanks to u.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad that we've finally made through this :)